# Webhook Data Input Parameter Syntax in Azure's Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have 5 parameters {[string]$VMName,  [string]$ResourceGroupName,  [string]$UserName,  [string]$Paswd,  [string]$UserDirectory,  [string]$RequestType}  in my runbook code what will be Webhookdata input parameter(json) syntax in Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass Json object  to the runbook you need to follow the below steps :

1. You need to  create a JSON file that contains all parameters & save it as test.json file.

   ```
    {
         "VMName" : "",
         "ResourceGroupName" : "",
         "UserName" : "",
         "Paswd" : "",
         "UserDirectory" : "",
         "RequestType" : ""
    }
   ```
2. convert the JSON code to a string

   `$json =  (Get-content -path 'JsonPath\test.json' -Raw) | Out-string`
3. Convert the string to a PowerShell object before passing it to the runbook.

   `$JsonParams = @{"json"=$json}`
4. Create a hash table for the parameters

```
$RBParams = @{
             AutomationAccountName = '<AutomationAccountName'
             ResourceGroupName = '<resourcegroup_name>'
             Name = 'Test-Json'
             Parameters = $JsonParams
        }
```

5. Start the run book

```
 $job = Start-AzAutomationRunbook @RBParams
```

For more information you can refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/runbook-input-parameters#pass-a-json-object-to-a-runbook).